# Laravel valet. 'Use of undefined constant SORTDATE - assumed 'SORTDATE'

Tags: php, laravel, macos, imap

Добрый, день. Есть проект на ларавеле, уже живет год. Захотелось попробовать новое окружение разработки VALET. Накатил на Sierra osx. В проекте есть пакеты использующие php-imap, соответственно установил соответсвующее расширение. Почта не ходит и в логе ошибки о использовании не определенной константы. 'Use of undefined constant SORTDATE - assumed 'SORTDATE'in Users/vlad/Code/macpwn/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:780
Насколько я понимаю дропается на этапе сборки сервис провайдеров.Когда подключается из вендоров пакет для работы с почтой. Константа эта определана в  http://php.net/manual/en/imap.constants.php
Пакет установленный в проекте использует несколько констант.
'by'    => [
            'date'      => SORTDATE,
            'arrival'   => SORTARRIVAL,
            'from'      => SORTFROM,
            'subject'   => SORTSUBJECT,
            'size'      => SORTSIZE
        ]
Что собственно ставит в тупик. Если я в любом месте проекта проверю значение этих констант, то увижу корректные значения. phpinfo() любезно мне сообщает что IMAP подключен. Но почему то когда собирается ядро фреймворка в логе эти ошибки ну и почта соответственно не ходит.
Этот же проект нормально работает в окружении Homestead.
Не могу понять в чем проблема. У кого есть идеи буду рад услышать.

Как выяснилось ошибка возникает при выполнении скрипта расписания, и сооответсвенно все что в запускается по расписанию не работает. Если запускать из консоли все скрипты отрабатывают нормально. Как видется причина в том что консольная комманда запускается в том окружении в котором для пхп не подключен IMAP. Остается понять как формируется окружение для скиптов выполняемых по сron.

Вот мой крон

PATH=/usr/local/opt/php70/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

- - - - - php /Users/vlad/Code/macpwn/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

список путей взят из окружения консоли в которой эта команда работает ок.  Но после добавления PATH крон перестал запускаться.

Comment: Все заработало.